# segmentation fault when i upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault

I did an upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. After the upgrade, I wrote a very simple perl program and tried to run it. It gave me Segmentation Error (core dumped) as an error. I used commands:

```
which perl 
which perl -v
```

and they show `/usr/bin/perl`
SCRIPT

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "string";
print $a,"\n";
```

Segmentation error(core dumped)

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Did the error give you a line number or any other information? Could you please post a link to your perl script? Since you wrote the script *after* the upgrade, it seems like the upgrade may be unrelated to this issue.

Comment: post the script on your question

Comment: Please have a look at the script. It is a very simple program.

Comment: running your script i get `string` so i assume that the sourcecode is totally fine and something with your perl packages must be broken. 

try to reinstall perl maybe